# System 'on' and Site 'on' - Can you keep a channel segment 'closed'?

Tags: ee2, channel, development

What is the best way to continue building a large site segment in which content can be added, previewed, and edited while the site is live but not seen in certain channels?

I have multiple ways of doing this, but I am always open to learn newer or better ways to improve my workflow.

Here's the situation: I have a large MSM site which consists of multiple subdomains. The old site is still live as the rebuild has to happen along side of the original which is a kluge of .net, static, EE1, etc..

So as the new site is designed and the old site becomes obsolete, I will need to open up various segments of the redesign (new), and close off the old site. Using 301's for the old content to the new content should help me with keeping my "juice" and traffic stats, but I am unsure of the best way to handle continuous development in the rebuild site.

If I have www.mydomain.com and say three channels as market-1, market-2, and market-3. I will build out market-1 and have it "live". While this is the case, I need to be able to develop in market-2 and market-3, adding entries, testing, etc. Is this possible without doing it on a development install and needing to port all of the fieldtypes, entries, etc. over? This is what I would like to avoid. I was hoping for a way to "close" a channeluntil it is ready for production viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "channel segment" or a URL segment?

In case of URL segments, you can protect the templates using:

```
{if 0 == logged_in_member_id }
{redirect='404'}
{/if}
```

Or you can restrict the access [to the templates by CP](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/template_access.html).

Comment: WOW!!! Was I ever over complicating this...  lol